# coqc: -Q.PLF: no such file or directory

Tags: coq, coqide

I am trying to compile a file hw5.v in coq which is in the plf folder of software foundations. I want to resolve the bindings and hence I use the command :

coqc -Q.PLF hw5.v

But it does not compile and gives the error as coqc: -Q.PLF: no such file or directory.
This has never happened before. If I do man coqc or coqc -v, it gives me the correct output. But it is not working with -Q or -R. Any idea to resolve this? my coq version is : 8.9.1

Comment: Does it work if you enter `coqc -Q . PLF hw5.v`?

Comment: gosh that worked!! did not know space was causing the issue..thanks a lot

Comment: Can one of you add an answer to this question?  Until now the solution only appears in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Putting the answer from the comments to close the question.)

The correct command is `coqc -Q . PLF hw5.v`, so that `-Q`, `.` and `PLF` are different arguments to the command-line program `coqc`.